# Animating sprites on top of mapview (iOS)

Tags: ios, annotations, mapkit

I am developing an application which will show where trains are at any given time. It will receive gpx-data from the trains to get their location.

Is there any way to animate a sprite moving along a restricted line in a mapview? In my example, a train moving along a trainroute.

I have drawn the trainroutes as polyline in an overlay, and the train is an annotation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up making a visible overlay, then making a separate array out of the same coordinates.

To simulate the movement, the MKAnnotations uses 'setCoordinate' while iterating the array, which in fact is the same as the overlay.

This made the annotations look like they moved atop of a restricted overlay.